# How to insert pdf into postgresql(remote db)

Tags: postgresql, pdf, remote-access, insert-update

I have a pdffile.

I could insert the pdf file and db is available in same server using below function and command.

function

```
create or replace function bytea_import(p_path text, p_result out bytea) 
                   language plpgsql as $$
declare
  l_oid oid;
  r record;
begin
  p_result := '';
  select lo_import(p_path) into l_oid;
  for r in ( select data 
             from pg_largeobject 
             where loid = l_oid 
             order by pageno ) loop
    p_result = p_result || r.data;
  end loop;
  perform lo_unlink(l_oid);
end;$$;
```

command:

```
 update jicontentresource set  data = bytea_import('/root/Desktop/Avinash/Avinash.pdf')
 where id =245
```

When file is in local server and, db is available in another server (remote)

If i try to do for remote server, using below command

```
update jicontentresource set  data = bytea_import('/root/Desktop/Avinash/Avinash.pdf') where id =245
```

it is not able to take file from local.

is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to do that with a PostgreSQL function, because that function runs on the database server, while the file is on the file system on the client side.

You'll have to write code in a client side programming language and read and import the file this way.

Depending on the API you are using, you could read the file into memory and use `INSERT`or `UPDATE`, or you could use the `COPY ... FROM STDIN` SQL command.

Answer (score 0):

you can just **separate local and remote** stuff:

```
create or replace function bytea_import(l_oid int, p_result out bytea) 
                   language plpgsql as $$
declare
  l_oid oid;
  r record;
begin
  p_result := '';
  for r in ( select data 
             from pg_largeobject 
             where loid = l_oid 
             order by pageno ) loop
    p_result = p_result || r.data;
  end loop;
  perform lo_unlink(l_oid);
end;$$;
```

**then run on client side:**

```
t=# select lo_import('/tmp/build.start');
 lo_import
-----------
 447349949
(1 row)
 update jicontentresource set  data = bytea_import(447349949)
 where id =245
```

Comment: can you pls elobarate with an example or a link to find a similar example my local machine is windows and remote is linux machine

Comment: i have run function on server side and on client side when i run the given query, it has thrown me follwong erro
function bytea_import(integer) does not exist
LINE 1: update jicontentresource set  data = bytea_import(43945)
                                             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
********** Error **********
ERROR: function bytea_import(integer) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 38